# Why can't I pack certain JARs outside WEB-INF

Tags: maven, pom.xml, java-web-start, jnlp

I have read in several blogs that it is not advised (or not possible)to pack jars outside the WEB-INF folder. I am curious as to know why this is so..

For instatnce,

```
mainStuff.war
|
|-->WEB-INF
|   |
|   |-->lib     (having many jars, used by the contents of specificStuff.jar
|   |-->classes
|   |-->web.xml
|
|-->META-INF        (having the .MF file and signed files .SF and .DSA)
|
|
|-->index.jsp       (consists of a jnlp xml, referring to the jars in lib)
|
|
|-->specificStuff.jar   (this is a separate jar module, which is mentioned in the POM of the war)
```

In the jnlp configuration in index.jsp, i am referring to the jars in lib like:

```
  <resources>     
    <java version="1.6+"/>
    <jar href="specificStuff.jar"/> 
    <jar href="lib/someJarthatIneed.jar"/>
  </resources>
```

Now, when i launch my JNLP, I get the error that someJarthatIneed failed to load. However, when i manually moved the lib outside WEB-INF, this error did not occur.

So, what I need to know is that, is there any way to pack the lib folder and all jars outside WEB-INF??
OR
Why is it that my jnlp (which is outside WEB-INF) not able to load the jar from WEB-INF/lib.
(I tried changing the path of jar as

```
<jar href="WEB-INF/lib/someJarthatIneed.jar"/>
```

but it did not work either..)

Any help on this will be apprciated. :)

Comment: The deployment model is not clear. Do you have a WAR file that serves downloadable code to be installed via JNLP? Or is the WAR file itself to be installed via JNLP?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? There is absolutely no reason to do it. Which is why you'll find it hard to do...

Comment: Actually, the specificStuff.jar is the real application thats downloaded via jnlp. All the dependencies of this jar are put inside the lib folder.

Also, the entire war itself is packed in a EAR -(thought this info is not required in this important in the above context)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the suggestions... But, I found a way to do it..

I used the maven-dependency-plugin (copy-dependencies) to copy all the dependency jars to a folder lib to a specified location.

```
<plugin>      
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/lib</outputDirectory>
                <includeScope>compile</includeScope>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Then use

```
  <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/</packagingExcludes>
```

in the pom, where you are using maven-war-plugin to make the war, to remove the lib folder from WEB-INF..

So, now the index.jsp is able to fetch all the jars from the lib.

Answer (score 0):

What is in WEB-INF is not available from http requests, and what is not in WEB-INF will be considered as resources and thus will not be loaded by the container.

If the jars you put in the WEB-INF/lib is not required by your application, simply moves them outside the WEB-INF folder, and they will be treated as resources.

You can also think about building an "uberjar" for you JNLP jar, packing all dependencies into a single jar.

Comment: thanks for the response... 
I was thinking about building the UBERJAR.. but, will i be able sign all the jars within the uberjar as well, using the jarsigner? also, will the jars be accessible from my index.jsp which has all the jnlp configurations..?