# How to WAR package JNLP downloadable JARs outside WEB-INF/lib?

Tags: maven, jar, dependencies, jnlp

My `war` has a very standard directory structure for `Tomcat 7` deployment, with a `WEB-INF` directory containing *classes*, *lib* etc. The only thing different is that I have a `webstart` as part of my app and that sits in a *webstart* directory at the top (same level as WEB-INF) of the war.  Inside it is the `jnlp` config as well as a lib directory containing just the JAR dependencies of the webstart (as opposed to the ones the web app uses that are in `WEB-INF/lib`) so that they are in a downloadable path, just like my javascript, css etc. Of course, the jar dependencies of the main web app do not need to be in a downloadable path, so WEB-INF/lib works there.

This present a build disruption as I can't include the webstart and its libs in the WAR build, instead it is not there but once the WAR is deployed, another script inelegantly injects the webstart directory into the deployed application directory of the webstart, along with the dependencies.

How can I generate a WAR that contains JNLP along with its lib dependencies in a downloadable path so they are all there once the war gets deployed seamlessly?

<sub>RELATED: [Why can't I pack certain JARs outside WEB-INF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35315546/why-cant-i-pack-certain-jars-outside-web-inf)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Maven Dependency Plugin with the copy-dependencies goal](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html) as shown below. Here you will have to specify all the artifacts one by one within the `<artifactItem>` tag.
Also, use the `<outputDirectory>` tag to specify the location where you want these artifacts to get copied.

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.10</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <artifactItems>
                <artifactItem>
                  <groupId>[ groupId ]</groupId>
                  <artifactId>[ artifactId ]</artifactId>
                  <version>[ version ]</version>
                  <type>[ packaging ]</type>
                  <classifier> [classifier - optional] </classifier>
                  <overWrite>[ true or false ]</overWrite>
                  <outputDirectory>[ output directory ]</outputDirectory>
                  <destFileName>[ filename ]</destFileName>
                </artifactItem>
                <artifactItem>
                  <groupId>[ groupId ]</groupId>
                  <artifactId>[ artifactId ]</artifactId>
                  <version>[ version ]</version>
                  <type>[ packaging ]</type>
                  <classifier> [classifier - optional] </classifier>
                  <overWrite>[ true or false ]</overWrite>
                  <outputDirectory>[ output directory ]</outputDirectory>
                  <destFileName>[ filename ]</destFileName>
                </artifactItem>
                ....
                .... Specify all the artifacts like mentioned above that you want to copy to a specified location

              </artifactItems>
              <!-- other configurations here -->
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

You can also have a look at the [Webstart Maven Plugin](https://github.com/KiranMohan/dynamic-tree-javaws-sample-project).